# Can you sort installed VS Code extensions by category, like the built-in ones?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When looking at VS Code extensions, I noticed that when you type in "@builtin" it automatically sorts and divides the built-in extensions by category. Picture below to show what I mean:

[image: list of built in VS Code extensions divided by category]

I would find this to be super useful for examining my @installed or even not yet installed extensions. I don't see where to set this view, though. You can choose a category, yes, but that's not remotely the same. Definitely with my @installed extensions I'd like to have them automatically sorted. If it's not possible (I see many of the @builtin extensions are listed as "Features", which doesn't seem like an actual category), and there's already been a feature request, can someone point me to it so I don't duplicate? Thanks.

Comment: If an extension is built-in, then it is installed. If it didn't come installed, then it wouldn't be built-in.

Comment: @jD3V But not all installed extensions are built in. Most are installed later. Those are the ones I'm asking about.

Answer (score 3):

I think the only sorting of installed extensions is coming in vscode v1.72, see [Release Notes: sorting installed extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_72.md#sorting-of-installed-extensions):

Click on the `filter` icon next to the `Extensions: Installed` head and choose `Sort By...`.

> You can now sort the list of installed extensions by **Install Count**,
> **Rating**, **Name**, **Published Date**, and **Updated Date**.

[image: sorting installed extensions]